# Make file system/partition Read-Only for archiving purposes

Tags: filesystem, ext4, read-only

I have found a couple of questions relating to file systems which are in Read-Only mode after failure and how to make them writable again.
I want to achieve the exact opposite.

I have 3.5" Hard disks formatted in ext4 with archive files on them.
The HardDisks are internal drives, on them is plain data, no operating system. (Like a data backup)

I want to make the file System read-only as opposed to read-only mounting or changing permissions on the files.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be [via the `e2fsprogs` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/e2fsprogs). When installed, you can set an `Ext4` partition as read-only like this:

```
sudo tune2fs -O read-only /dev/sdXY
```

<sup>**Note:** Setting partition attributes is done via `tune2fs` with packages provided by `e2fsprogs` [as per the documentation for `Ext4`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/ext4.5.html).</sup>

In the event you change your mind later about having the partition set as read only, you can remove the setting like this:

```
sudo tune2fs -O ^read-only /dev/sdXY
```

<sup>**Note:** The `^` acts as “unset”.</sup>

Comment: thank you for the nice sugestion. I will try it. 
I hope, I can still access the data from other machines, which do not have tune2fs installed?

Comment: works great. at least my on ubuntu server 20.04 lts, `tune2fs` came preinstalled.